# Hipay on multistore multiple currency/language issue

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, payment

I'm using hipay on my magento 1.9. Indeed, I have 2 sub account on hipay :
the first one uses french and euro, the second one uses english and pound.
The problem is when a client choose english and euro / frenchand pound
and try to final checkout it redirects to empty cart.
Do you have any clue?